# How do I lock the workstation from a windows service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, locking

I need to lock the workstation from a windows service written in VB.Net. I am writing the app on Windows 7 but it needs to work under Vista and XP as well.

User32 API LockWorkStation does not work as it requires an interactive desktop and I get return value of 0.

I tried calling %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation from both a Process and from Shell, but still nothing happens.

Setting the service to interact with the desktop is a no-go as I am running the service under the admin account so it can do some other stuff that requires admin rights - like disabling the network, and you can only select the interact with desktop option if running under Local System Account.

That would be secondary question - how to run another app with admin rights from a service running under Local System Account without bugging the user.

I am writing an app to control my kids computer/internet access (which I plan to open source when done) so I need everything to happen as stealthily as possible.

I have a UI that handles settings and status notifications in the taskbar, but that is easy to kill and thus defeat the locking. I could make another hidden Windows Forms app to handle the locking, but that just seems a rather inelegant solution.

Better ideas anyone?

Comment: how is locking the workstation stealthy?

Comment: I want the source of the lock to be stealthy, and/or at hard to kill. Don't want to make it too easy for the kids to find and defeat the app. The effect - internet going down and/or computer locked, well no, definitely not stealthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am am not totally satisfied with my answer but Window's security leaves me little alternative. Anything opened bu the service (through Process, Shell whatever) will not have desktop access. I understand the reasons behind the limitations Microsoft has created but still frustrating!

My Service uses IPC to tell my UI to lock the computer. Here is a basic link on doing that:

http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/2007/08/09/simple-inter-process-communication-in-vbnet/

See his reference links for additional data.

However, that still does not quite work. Also see this link for how to do it without the Access Is Denied messages:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/ce968b5b-04fe-46d2-bb75-73e367a8b0c3

Make sure your URIs are correct. The portName property on the server side is the first part of the IPC path in the GetObject method call. The second part maps to the second parameter of the RegisterWellKnownServiceType call on the server side.

And apparently the portName properties need to be DIFFERENT on the sever and client sides.

If you get "Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified." on your client then the server has not started yet so there is nothing to hear you scream.

Answer (score 6):

I've been fighting with this over a week and after reading a lot of information about this issue, finally got the solution for this...

You have to use the CreateProcessAsUser function like this:

```
  Private Shared Sub Executer(ByVal content As String)
    Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process

    Dim filename As String
    filename = "e:\lock.bat" 
    'create a bat file with ''rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation'' inside

    Dim UserTokenHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    WindowsApi.WTSQueryUserToken(WindowsApi.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId, UserTokenHandle)

    Dim ProcInfo As New WindowsApi.PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim StartInfo As New WindowsApi.STARTUPINFOW
    StartInfo.cb = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(StartInfo))

    WindowsApi.CreateProcessAsUser(UserTokenHandle, filename, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, False, 0, IntPtr.Zero, Nothing, StartInfo, ProcInfo)
    If Not UserTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
        WindowsApi.CloseHandle(UserTokenHandle)
    End If

End Sub
```

Got most of the code from [here](http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2011/06/10/vb-net-start-process-in-console-session-from-windows-service-on-windows-7/) where you can, also, find the WindowsApi to use with this function. 
I'me still trying to find if can avoid the bat file but at least is a very decent solution.

EDIT:
To avoid using an external *.bat file to execute the code just edit the WindowsApi Class and replace the CreateProcessAsUser and the advapi32.dll import part with this:

```
    <DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateProcessAsUser", ExactSpelling:=False,      SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Shared Function CreateProcessAsUser( _
                       ByVal hToken As IntPtr, _
                       ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
                       <[In](), Out(), [Optional]()> ByVal lpCommandLine As StringBuilder, _
                       ByVal lpProcessAttributes As IntPtr, _
                       ByVal lpThreadAttributes As IntPtr, _
                       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bInheritHandles As Boolean, _
                       ByVal dwCreationFlags As Integer, _
                       ByVal lpEnvironment As IntPtr, _
                       ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, _
                       <[In]()> ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFOW, _
                       <Out()> ByRef lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
```

And now you can use a stringbuilder as the thrid argument(comandline) for CreateProcessAsUser function and put the second(applicationame) as 'Nothing' like this:

```
Dim cmdline As New StringBuilder
cmdline.Append("rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation")
WindowsApi.CreateProcessAsUser(UserTokenHandle, Nothing, cmdline, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, False, 0, IntPtr.Zero, Nothing, StartInfo, ProcInfo)
```

And it WILL WORK!!!!

Regards,
AP

Comment: Yes, it works even rewritten to VC++ :) The only thing that was different for me: if I wanted to overcome the need for creating the bat file, I put second argument (applicationName) to NULL, and the rundll command came to the third argument. That did not work. What works is `CreateProcessAsUser(userToken, L"rundll32.exe", L"rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation", NULL, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is actively blocked by Microsoft - if you did get it working, it'd be exploiting a loophole that will surely be closed soon.

What you can do though is the [Friar Tuck/Robin Hood](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~magi/personal/humour/Computer_Folklore/Robin%20Hood%20And%20Friar%20Tuck.html) solution - have two programs running and monitoring each other. When one is killed, the other detects this and restarts it (or, just logs the current user out as punishment, depending on how severe you want this to be).

Comment: I don't know if this still works, but I an old Windows app I made for an April Fools Day would start a new copy of itself in response to WM_CLOSE. That way, Windows was happy (no "this program is not responding..." dialog) yet the little monster was still running.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I am working on a version of the Robin Hood (the service) /Friar Tuck (the UI) solution. As usual permission issues prevent me from doing it the simple way - capture the service process and attach an Exit event. I will have to use a timer. I can probably do that from the service to watch the UI though.

Any advice on the best way to signal the UI to handle the lock?

Comment: Ok, it looks like I am going to give up on the Robin Hood/Friar Tuck solution for now. Security issues are preventing the UI from starting a service (permission denied when I do a controller.Start()). I will circle back to hardening the application at a later time.

Comment: @Brad Mathews - my idea was that the two programs would be run as regular programs, not services. I really don't think you can do what you want from a service.

Comment: hmm.... That would certainly harden the UI. One would run hidden. And like the service the name would provide some obfuscation. Also, I just learned that you can set a service to ignore stop requests - have yet to try it. That in combination with automatic service recovery options would provide a fairly high, though not insurmountable, wall around the service.

Answer (score 1):

Another inelegant solution (but without the drawbacks of signaling your UI application) is to have another service that is installed to interact with the desktop whose job it is to listen for a signal to lock the desktop.

I agree that it's not great  to have to run with local system credentials, but if all the service does is lock the desktop, there's a pretty small footprint that needs secured.

Comment: I think this is a great way to go.

Comment: Interacting with the desktop is history since session 0 isolation.

Comment: I do not know the difficulty in signaling the UI from a service yet, but I want to avoid adding another piece (2 services plus the UI). Also, I heard that interacting with the desktop was deprecated in Vista, but I see it back in 7. (I skipped Vista myself). Not sure if I can trust it to stay around? 

Thoughts?

Comment: I had forgotten about the tightening up of the session 0 access to the desktop. It seems that my suggestion is probably too fragile with dependencies on how various versions of Windows let (or prevent) services from interacting with the desktop. I agree that having 2 services would leave something to be desired (assuming it even works). I'd have to do some research to come up with answers (so I'm probably not the best resource).

I'd have to do some reaserch to

Answer (score 0):

You could try to launch a screensaver from a windows service that automatically locks the workstation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with user session in a service, you first need to use a user session id. basically you'll need to use `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` and `CreateEnvironmentBlock` prior to calling `CreateProcessAsUser`.
The important part is the `CreateEnvironmentBlock`. The first two methods allow us not to use a predefiend username/password which is desirable . 
The Python snippet as a proof of concept for locking the workstation from a service is as follow :

```py
import win32process
import win32con
import win32ts

console_session_id = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
console_user_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console_session_id)
startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
environment = win32profile.CreateEnvironmentBlock(console_user_token, False)
handle, thread_id ,pid, tid = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(console_user_token, None, "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation", None, None, True, priority, environment, None, startup)
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589139/how-is-it-possible-to-lock-windows-from-a-windows-service/60598132#60598132)