# How is it possible to lock windows from a windows service?

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm writing a windows service in Python, which at some point needs to lock windows if a specific condition happens (for example the person leaves the pc un-attended for some time). 
The solution I found was to use `user32.LockWorkStation()` using the `ctypes` module.

```py
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

However, after failing at locking the OS, I noticed the LockWorkstation specifically works in the 
interactive [desktop] mode which windows services do not support. it actually wasted quite a bit of my time as it works when debugging! any way,

Quoting from [LockWorkStation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The LockWorkStation function is callable only by processes running on
>   the interactive desktop. In addition, the user must be logged on, and
>   the workstation cannot already be locked.

windows services do have a property where you can allow it to interact with the desktop (on log on tab), however, this feature is if I'm not mistaken, disabled on latest versions of windows and apart from that, is not a good idea to enable it either.

Also quoting from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):

> Services do not have message loops, unless they are allowed to
>   interact with the desktop. If the message loop is not provided by a
>   hidden form, as in this example, the service must be run under the
>   local system account, and manual intervention is required to enable
>   interaction with the desktop. That is, the administrator must manually
>   check the Allow service to interact with desktop check box on the Log
>   On tab of the service properties dialog box. In that case, a message
>   loop is automatically provided. This option is available only when the
>   service is run under the local system account. Interaction with the
>   desktop cannot be enabled programmatically.

Therefore I'm looking for other solutions that would allow me to lock the windows from a windows service. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

In order to interact with user session in a service, you first need to use a user session id. Basically you'll need to use `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` and `CreateEnvironmentBlock` prior to calling `CreateProcessAsUser`. Here is the snippet that does the trick:

```py
import win32process
import win32con
import win32ts

console_session_id = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
console_user_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console_session_id)
startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
environment = win32profile.CreateEnvironmentBlock(console_user_token, False)
handle, thread_id ,pid, tid = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(console_user_token, None, "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation", None, None, True, priority, environment, None, startup)
```

If you need to call a specific application you may call this like this:

```py
win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(console_user_token, your_app_exe, app_args, None, None, True, priority, environment, None, startup)
```

This is actually how services in windows interact with user sessions. Using this method, you no longer need the user credentials.

### Long Explanation:

When it comes to Windows services to access/interact with user session (session >0). It's usually recommended to use CreateProcessAsUser(). one would go on and do something like this ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616591/2736559)):

```py
user = "username"
pword = "123456"
domain = "." # means current domain

logontype = win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE
# some may suggest to use BATCH mode instead in case you fail! but this doesn't work either!
# logontype = win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH
provider = win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50
token = win32security.LogonUser(user, domain, pword, logontype, provider)

startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
lock_file = os.path.join(cwd,'system_locker.exe')
appname = lock_file 
priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
result = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(token, appname, None, None, None, True, priority, None, None, startup)
```

but if you go this way, You'll face the error :

```
(1314, 'CreateProcessAsUser', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')
```

There are many suggestions to get rid of this issue, such as disabling UAC, [etc](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/error-0x80070522-build-10074-a-required-privilege/516f87a8-80a6-4acb-a278-8866b2080460). but none will work and if you look at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) documentation about [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera), you'll see :

> Typically, the process that calls the CreateProcessAsUser function
>   must have the SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME privilege and may require the
>   SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilege if the token is not assignable.
>   If this function fails with ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD (1314), use the
>   CreateProcessWithLogonW function instead. CreateProcessWithLogonW
>   requires no special privileges, but the specified user account must be
>   allowed to log on interactively. Generally, it is best to use
>   CreateProcessWithLogonW to create a process with alternate
>   credentials.

which means to use `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. If one goes and tries this for example like this :

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400

CData = Array.__base__
LPBYTE = POINTER(BYTE)


class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    '''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873'''
    _fields_ = [
        ('hProcess', HANDLE),
        ('hThread', HANDLE),
        ('dwProcessId', DWORD),
        ('dwThreadId', DWORD),
    ]


LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)


class STARTUPINFOW(Structure):
    'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331'
    _fields_ = [
        ('cb', DWORD),
        ('lpReserved', LPWSTR),
        ('lpDesktop', LPWSTR),
        ('lpTitle', LPWSTR),
        ('dwX', DWORD),
        ('dwY', DWORD),
        ('dwXSize', DWORD),
        ('dwYSize', DWORD),
        ('dwXCountChars', DWORD),
        ('dwYCountChars', DWORD),
        ('dwFillAttribute', DWORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD),
        ('wShowWindow', WORD),
        ('cbReserved2', WORD),
        ('lpReserved2', LPBYTE),
        ('hStdInput', HANDLE),
        ('hStdOutput', HANDLE),
        ('hStdError', HANDLE),
    ]


LPSTARTUPINFOW = POINTER(STARTUPINFOW)


# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431
windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW.restype = BOOL
windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW.argtypes = [
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpUsername
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpDomain
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpPassword
                                                    DWORD,  # dwLogonFlags
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpApplicationName
                                                    LPWSTR,  # lpCommandLine (inout)
                                                    DWORD,  # dwCreationFlags
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpEnvironment  (force Unicode)
                                                    LPCWSTR,  # lpCurrentDirectory
                                                    LPSTARTUPINFOW,  # lpStartupInfo
                                                    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION,  # lpProcessInfo (out)
                                                ]


def CreateProcessWithLogonW(
                            lpUsername=None,
                            lpDomain=None,
                            lpPassword=None,
                            dwLogonFlags=0,
                            lpApplicationName=None,
                            lpCommandLine=None,
                            dwCreationFlags=0,
                            lpEnvironment=None,
                            lpCurrentDirectory=None,
                            startupInfo=None
):
    if (lpCommandLine is not None and
            not isinstance(lpCommandLine, CData)
        ):
        lpCommandLine = create_unicode_buffer(lpCommandLine)
    dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT
    if startupInfo is None:
        startupInfo = STARTUPINFOW(sizeof(STARTUPINFOW))
    processInformation = PROCESS_INFORMATION(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    success = windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
        lpUsername, lpDomain, lpPassword, dwLogonFlags, lpApplicationName,
        lpCommandLine, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentDirectory,
        byref(startupInfo), byref(processInformation))
    if not success:
        raise WinError()
    return processInformation

....

result = CreateProcessWithLogonW(user, domain, pword, 0, None, "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation")
```

He/she will face the error :

```
(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

Another similar implementation that fails is as follows (taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29737399/2736559)):

```py
from ctypes import wintypes
from subprocess import PIPE

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error=True)

ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 0x0006
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
INVALID_DWORD_VALUE = wintypes.DWORD(-1).value

DEBUG_PROCESS                    = 0x00000001
DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS          = 0x00000002
CREATE_SUSPENDED                 = 0x00000004
DETACHED_PROCESS                 = 0x00000008
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE               = 0x00000010
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP         = 0x00000200
CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT       = 0x00000400
CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM          = 0x00000800
CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM            = 0x00001000
INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY          = 0x00010000
CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS         = 0x00040000
EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT     = 0x00080000
CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB        = 0x01000000
CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000
CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE        = 0x04000000
CREATE_NO_WINDOW                 = 0x08000000

STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW    = 0x00000001
STARTF_USESIZE          = 0x00000002
STARTF_USEPOSITION      = 0x00000004
STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS    = 0x00000008
STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010
STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN    = 0x00000020
STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK  = 0x00000040
STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080
STARTF_USESTDHANDLES    = 0x00000100
STARTF_USEHOTKEY        = 0x00000200
STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME  = 0x00000800
STARTF_TITLEISAPPID     = 0x00001000
STARTF_PREVENTPINNING   = 0x00002000

SW_HIDE            = 0
SW_SHOWNORMAL      = 1
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
SW_SHOW            = 5
SW_MINIMIZE        = 6
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
SW_SHOWNA          = 8
SW_RESTORE         = 9
SW_SHOWDEFAULT     = 10 # ~STARTUPINFO
SW_FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11

LOGON_WITH_PROFILE        = 0x00000001
LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY = 0x00000002

STD_INPUT_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-10).value
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = wintypes.DWORD(-11).value
STD_ERROR_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-12).value

class HANDLE(wintypes.HANDLE):
    __slots__ = 'closed',

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value or 0

    def Detach(self):
        if not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            self.closed = True
            value = int(self)
            self.value = None
            return value
        raise ValueError("already closed")

    def Close(self, CloseHandle=kernel32.CloseHandle):
        if self and not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            CloseHandle(self.Detach())

    __del__ = Close

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%d)" % (self.__class__.__name__, int(self))

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873"""
    __slots__ = '_cached_hProcess', '_cached_hThread'

    _fields_ = (('_hProcess',   HANDLE),
                ('_hThread',    HANDLE),
                ('dwProcessId', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwThreadId',  wintypes.DWORD))

    @property
    def hProcess(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hProcess'):
            self._cached_hProcess = self._hProcess
        return self._cached_hProcess

    @property
    def hThread(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hThread'):
            self._cached_hThread = self._hThread
        return self._cached_hThread

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.hProcess.Close()
        finally:
            self.hThread.Close()

LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = ctypes.POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)

LPBYTE = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)

class STARTUPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331"""
    _fields_ = (('cb',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpReserved',      wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpDesktop',       wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpTitle',         wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('dwX',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwY',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFillAttribute', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFlags',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('wShowWindow',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('cbReserved2',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('lpReserved2',     LPBYTE),
                ('hStdInput',       wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdOutput',      wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdError',       wintypes.HANDLE))

    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.cb = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(STARTUPINFO, self).__init__(**kwds)

class PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST = ctypes.POINTER(PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)

class STARTUPINFOEX(STARTUPINFO):
    _fields_ = (('lpAttributeList', PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST),)

LPSTARTUPINFO = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFO)
LPSTARTUPINFOEX = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFOEX)

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('nLength',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpSecurityDescriptor', wintypes.LPVOID),
                ('bInheritHandle',       wintypes.BOOL))
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.nLength = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, self).__init__(**kwds)

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = ctypes.POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)

class HANDLE_IHV(HANDLE):
    pass

class DWORD_IDV(wintypes.DWORD):
    pass

def _check_ihv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_idv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_DWORD_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

def WIN(func, restype, *argtypes):
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    if issubclass(restype, HANDLE_IHV):
        func.errcheck = _check_ihv
    elif issubclass(restype, DWORD_IDV):
        func.errcheck = _check_idv
    else:
        func.errcheck = _check_bool

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211
WIN(kernel32.CloseHandle, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ HANDLE hObject

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685086
WIN(kernel32.ResumeThread, DWORD_IDV,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ hThread

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425
WIN(kernel32.CreateProcessW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_opt_    hToken
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_        hToken
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpUsername
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpDomain
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpPassword
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation


CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL = 0
CREATION_TYPE_LOGON  = 1
CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN  = 2
CREATION_TYPE_USER   = 3

class CREATIONINFO(object):
    __slots__ = ('dwCreationType',
        'lpApplicationName', 'lpCommandLine', 'bUseShell',
        'lpProcessAttributes', 'lpThreadAttributes', 'bInheritHandles',
        'dwCreationFlags', 'lpEnvironment', 'lpCurrentDirectory',
        'hToken', 'lpUsername', 'lpDomain', 'lpPassword', 'dwLogonFlags')

    def __init__(self, dwCreationType=CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL,
                 lpApplicationName=None, lpCommandLine=None, bUseShell=False,
                 lpProcessAttributes=None, lpThreadAttributes=None,
                 bInheritHandles=False, dwCreationFlags=0, lpEnvironment=None,
                 lpCurrentDirectory=None, hToken=None, dwLogonFlags=0,
                 lpUsername=None, lpDomain=None, lpPassword=None):
        self.dwCreationType = dwCreationType
        self.lpApplicationName = lpApplicationName
        self.lpCommandLine = lpCommandLine
        self.bUseShell = bUseShell
        self.lpProcessAttributes = lpProcessAttributes
        self.lpThreadAttributes = lpThreadAttributes
        self.bInheritHandles = bInheritHandles
        self.dwCreationFlags = dwCreationFlags
        self.lpEnvironment = lpEnvironment
        self.lpCurrentDirectory = lpCurrentDirectory
        self.hToken = hToken
        self.lpUsername = lpUsername
        self.lpDomain = lpDomain
        self.lpPassword = lpPassword
        self.dwLogonFlags = dwLogonFlags

def create_environment(environ):
    if environ is not None:
        items = ['%s=%s' % (k, environ[k]) for k in sorted(environ)]
        buf = '\x00'.join(items)
        length = len(buf) + 2 if buf else 1
        return ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buf, length)

def create_process(commandline=None, creationinfo=None, startupinfo=None):
    if creationinfo is None:
        creationinfo = CREATIONINFO()

    if startupinfo is None:
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    elif isinstance(startupinfo, subprocess.STARTUPINFO):
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=startupinfo.dwFlags,
                        hStdInput=startupinfo.hStdInput,
                        hStdOutput=startupinfo.hStdOutput,
                        hStdError=startupinfo.hStdError,
                        wShowWindow=startupinfo.wShowWindow)

    si, ci, pi = startupinfo, creationinfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION()

    if commandline is None:
        commandline = ci.lpCommandLine

    if commandline is not None:
        if ci.bUseShell:
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
            comspec = os.environ.get("ComSpec", os.path.join(
                        os.environ["SystemRoot"], "System32", "cmd.exe"))
            commandline = '"{}" /c "{}"'.format(comspec, commandline)
        commandline = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(commandline)

    dwCreationFlags = ci.dwCreationFlags | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT
    lpEnvironment = create_environment(ci.lpEnvironment)

    if (dwCreationFlags & DETACHED_PROCESS and
       ((dwCreationFlags & CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) or
        (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON) or
        (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN))):
        raise RuntimeError('DETACHED_PROCESS is incompatible with '
                           'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, which is implied for '
                           'the logon and token creation types')

    if ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL:

        kernel32.CreateProcessW(
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes, ci.bInheritHandles,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON:

        advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
            ci.lpUsername, ci.lpDomain, ci.lpPassword, ci.dwLogonFlags,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN:

        advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            ci.hToken, ci.dwLogonFlags,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_USER:

        advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW(
            ci.hToken,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes, ci.bInheritHandles,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid process creation type')

    return pi

class Popen(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        ci = self._creationinfo = kwds.pop('creationinfo', CREATIONINFO())
        if kwds.pop('suspended', False):
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_SUSPENDED
        self._child_started = False
        super(Popen, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:

        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo,
                           creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite,
                           c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, types.StringTypes) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell, 
                    close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                    startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite, to_close)
    else:

        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags,
                           shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread,
                           errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            assert not pass_fds, "pass_fds not supported on Windows."
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, str) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell, 
                    close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                    startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite)

    def _common_execute_child(self, executable, commandline, shell,
                              close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                              startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite,
                              to_close=()):

        ci = self._creationinfo
        if executable is not None:
            ci.lpApplicationName = executable
        if commandline:
            ci.lpCommandLine = commandline
        if shell:
            ci.bUseShell = shell
        if not close_fds:
            ci.bInheritHandles = int(not close_fds)
        if creationflags:
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= creationflags
        if env is not None:
            ci.lpEnvironment = env
        if cwd is not None:
            ci.lpCurrentDirectory = cwd

        if startupinfo is None:
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        si = self._startupinfo = startupinfo

        default = None if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else -1
        if default not in (p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite):
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
            si.hStdInput  = int( p2cread)
            si.hStdOutput = int(c2pwrite)
            si.hStdError  = int(errwrite)

        try:
            pi = create_process(creationinfo=ci, startupinfo=si)
        finally:
            if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
                if p2cread is not None:
                    p2cread.Close()
                    to_close.remove(p2cread)
                if c2pwrite is not None:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(c2pwrite)
                if errwrite is not None:
                    errwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(errwrite)
            else:
                if p2cread != -1:
                    p2cread.Close()
                if c2pwrite != -1:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                if errwrite != -1:
                    errwrite.Close()
                if hasattr(self, '_devnull'):
                    os.close(self._devnull)

        if not ci.dwCreationFlags & CREATE_SUSPENDED:
            self._child_started = True

        # Retain the process handle, but close the thread handle
        # if it's no longer needed.
        self._processinfo = pi
        self._handle = pi.hProcess.Detach()
        self.pid = pi.dwProcessId
        if self._child_started:
            pi.hThread.Close()

    def start(self):
        if self._child_started:
            raise RuntimeError("processes can only be started once")
        hThread = self._processinfo.hThread
        prev_count = kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread)
        if prev_count > 1:
            for i in range(1, prev_count):
                if kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread) <= 1:
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('cannot start the main thread')
        # The thread's previous suspend count was 0 or 1, 
        # so it should be running now.
        self._child_started = True
        hThread.Close()

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._child_started:
            try:
                if hasattr(self, '_processinfo'):
                    self._processinfo.hThread.Close()
            finally:
                if hasattr(self, '_handle'):
                    self.terminate()
        super(Popen, self).__del__()

....

cmd = "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation" #lock_file
ci = CREATIONINFO(CREATION_TYPE_LOGON,
                 lpUsername=user,
                 lpPassword=pword)

p = Popen(cmd, suspended=True, creationinfo=ci,
          stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.start()
```

fails with the same error.

And then we reach to the final solution that actually works which is to use use `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` and `CreateEnvironmentBlock` prior to calling `CreateProcessAsUser`. The most important part imho, is the `CreateEnvironmentBlock` which is essential for this to work. The first two methods allow us not to use a predefined user/pass.

Useful links :

@EugeneMayevski'Callback provided two links that discusses about this as well:
1. [calling-createprocessasuser-from-service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f/calling-createprocessasuser-from-service)
2. [calling-createprocessasuser-from-a-user-process-launched-from-a-service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6cad447b-ee67-4c96-b190-5b6b78936aa5/calling-createprocessasuser-from-a-user-process-launched-from-a-service)

### Important Note :

In debug mode when using the snippet I provided, you may face the 1314 error for `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` its spected and the live service wont face this error and will run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with services being able or unable to interact with desktop, but with them being run in a separate [Windows Session](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361). Besides explaining your problem a lot, this article also suggests a possible solution:

> For more complex UI, use the CreateProcessAsUser function to create a process in the user's session.

You can even re-run python with your own script but in the user's session.

The difficulty here would be to determine, *which* session you should lock and which user you should impersonate for this. There can really be several users, logged in concurrently even locally. But most likely (if you are creating a service for yourself), you can simply impersonate the user on session 1.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I did use ```CreateProcessAsUser``` However, I get ```(1314, 'CreateProcessAsUser', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')``` error! if I'm not mistaken, CreateProcessAsUser is supposed to acquire needed previleges itself! yet it fails.

Comment: @Rika before calling CreateProcessAsUser, you need to call LogonUser to get a token of the impersonated user. Is it LogonUser that fails for you? Also, it looks like other people do the same as you do, and here's a couple of links with the code in them: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f/calling-createprocessasuser-from-service and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6cad447b-ee67-4c96-b190-5b6b78936aa5/calling-createprocessasuser-from-a-user-process-launched-from-a-service

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it. I did that as well and still that didnt work. I'll post the answer in couple of minutes.

Comment: oh my God! you were right! This was actually what I ultimately came to. its very weird I didn't find that. Thank you very very much.